# MVC postback, add rows to models list and redraw form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postback

I have a model that holds an order and orderrows.
The user may submit the form and in the postback we do some rowsplitting and rebuild the model and the rows. The problem is that the hidden fields gets the values based on the index in the list (have seen some post about this)

Some code:

```
Orderview to display the rows:
@Html.EditorFor(r => r.Rows)
```

The editor for the OrderRowModel

```
@Model.ItemNo @Html.HiddenFor(r => r.Id) @Html.HiddenFor(r => r.RowNumber)
```

Pseducode for update in controller

```
foreach(var r in model.Rows)
{
  if(qty>0) { 
    string errormsg = UpdateRow(r);
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errormsg))
       ErrorMsgList.Add(r.RowNo, errormsg);
  }
}
var reloadedModel = ReloadOrderAndRows(model.OrderNo);
foreach(var r in reloadedModel.Rows)
{
   if(HasError(r.RowNo, ErrorMsgList))
     r.Error = GetError(r.RowNo, ErrorMsgList);
}
return View(reloadedModel);
```

**Example**
I have an order with 3 rows (10,20,30)
the user update row 20 with a qty and do a postback. I save the row, but based on some business data the row will be splitted into row 20 and 21
In the model I reload whole model and sends it to the view
The view now displays 4 rows (10,20,21,30) but the hidden box for 21 got the id 30 (since 30 was on list position 2 before).
All the data fields qty and display fields are correct, it's the hidden field (and even if I change it to a editorfor function) that gets the wrong value.

So if the form is submitted again I will update the wrong row.

So, why don't I redirect to the orginal view after postback? If the update fails I set some data on the reloaded RowModel. And if I do a redirect I will loose all details set on row level.

I need somehow specify the unique id on inputsfields that relates to the rownumber or have the mvc to forget that it's a result of a postback. I see that the reloaded model have the correct values. It's like there is a viewstate setting my values.

**CAN'T ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION YET SO I DO THE ANSWER IN EDIT **

Ok, so it was the ModelState that hold the values. If i just did a output for RowNo i got the correct value, but the input was updated by the modelstate. So what I did now was to call the ModelState.Clear() before returning the view.

the only loss I can think of is that the qty will not be saved if error, something I can fix with setting values to the model in the controller.

```
ModelState.Clear()
```

Comment: This solution worked fine, thx for answering your own question :)